# Storing a collection of entities without traversing the collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ado.net

I wonder if it is possible to insert records into a table without having to iterate through my collection in this way, to improve performance.

```
using (DBEntities context = new DBEntities())
{
    foreach (var singular in plural)
    {
        context.EntitiDB.Add(singular);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `plural`? Is it an object connected with DB, or just an in-memory collection?

Comment: plural is a collection in-memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move SaveChanges() outside the loop:

```
using (DBEntities context = new DBEntities())
        {
            foreach (var singular in plural)
            {
                context.EntitiDB.Add(singular); 
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using context.EntitiDB.AddRange(plural)? Also I would assume that if you moved the context.SaveChanges() outside of the loop, that could improve performance.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, AddRange was introduced only in EF6

Comment: AddRange does not appear as option "context.EntitiDB." save and not save changes outside and I tried it. 

regards 

PD. noteworthy that "unique" is the same type as "EntitiDB"

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see that it was tagged with EF 4.

Comment: people 

apparently is a problem in data volume, why not poque operates as suggested by SoftwareFactor, Thanks